Galerkin method of plate bending
Is there a python program to calculate the Galerkin method of plate bending?  Has anyone found a solution to this problem before?
Men bu ish bo'yicha kod yozmoqchi edim. Kimdir bu borada samarali yechim topganmi?  .
.        .    .         .         .    .    .   .
